# How to do the calculation without any models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to get an integer(@integer) from the form in my root_path, do multiplication (@integer*45) and display the result on the same page. How can I do it without any models in my application?
Please, share your best practice. Thank you!

I was trying to do next:

CalculatorsController

```
def calculation
  @integer = params[:integer]
  @result = @integer*45
end

def result
end
```

root.rb

```
root :to => 'calculators#result'
resources :calculators, :collection=>{:result => :get, :calculation => :post}
```

calculators/result.html.erb

```
<% form_tag root_path, :html => {:method => :post} do %>
    <%= label_tag 'integer' %>
    <%= text_field_tag :integer %>

    <div><%= submit_tag 'OK' %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried up to now?

Comment: Refer to [*form_tag*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) with `remote` option.

Comment: @Pavan: `remote: true` is irrelevant here

Comment: @SergioTulentsev *display the result on the same page*

Comment: Lemme get this straight: you supposedly know how to do this with a model, right? To accomplish which you create a form, a controller, an action, in which you parse incoming form data and feed it to a model for saving. Now do all the same things, just don't use a model.

Comment: @Pavan: I took it to mean that it should render the same page, as opposed to a redirect to index path or whatever

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Oh yes! I thought *without refreshing* the page :)

Comment: @Pavan: that's another valid interpretation, yes.

Comment: the question is updated. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do it with *ajax*, so there is no need for page refresh:

First, update the routes, for your example you only need two routes, one `get` (or `root`) and one `post`.

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'calculators#result'
  post 'calculators/calculation'
end
```

Next, update your view:

1. Change the url in your `form_tag` where the data will be sent (to `calculation` action instead of `result`).
2. Add `remote: true` option to enable *ajax*.
3. Add a tag where you will display your result.

result.html.erb:

```
<% form_tag calculators_calculation_url, remote: true do %>
    <%= label_tag 'integer' %>
    <%= text_field_tag :integer %>

    <div><%= submit_tag 'OK' %></div>
<% end %>

<div id="total"></div>
```

And create a view for `calculation` action, but since you are using ajax, you will create it as `js.erb` and include the required javascript (or jQuery) to update your view (i'm using jQuery in the example).

calculation.js.erb:

```
$('#total').html('<%= @result %>')
```

Now when you click `submit`, your form will be sent to `calculation` action and will update the `div` with `@result`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the field to  your form...

```
<% form_tag root_path, :html => {:method => :post} do %>
    <%= label_tag 'integer' %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:integer, @integer) %>

    <% if @result.present? %>
      <br> 
      Result is: <%= @result %> 
      <br/>
    <% end %>

    <div><%= submit_tag 'OK' %></div>
<% end %>
```

And then render result in  your calculate...

```
def calculation
  @integer = params[:integer].to_i
  @result = @integer*45
  render :result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result view (*result.html.erb*) is getting its data from the *result* method, not *calculation*. Update your controller as follows:

```
    def calculation
      @integer = params[:integer]
    end

    def result
      @result = @integer*45
    end
```

You then need a tag to display your result in the view, something like:

```
<p> <%= @result %> </p>
```